# Detect a tab item is clicked though out the app

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to go to home tab (which is 3rd tab out of 5 tabs) when the tab item is pressed. I need this to happen when I'm in a view controller which is navigated from home tab too.

I tried `self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)`in viewWillAppear, viewDisappear and tab change.
But they don't work in every scenario.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please put code you have tried.

Comment: i edited the question

I tried self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)in viewWillAppear, viewDisappear and tab change. But they don't work in every scenario.